# Visual studio publish desktop application with editable file

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, desktop-application, publishing

I have a c# desktop application.
I need to let the application read a configuration file (editable by the final user) and use readed values to chenge application behavior.

I need that this file is editable when the app is published. What kind of file I need to use? Ore which kind of properties I need to put on this file?

Now I tryied with a xlsx file included in project. In debug It works fine, but When I publish the application, the xlsx became a xlsx.deploy file and I can't edit anymore.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a try.

project -> right click -> properties -> publishing -> options->Deployment。

[image]

[image]